# Wildfly 13 gzip filter properties

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, application-server

Earlier I was using Jboss 7.1, where I have configured below properties for gzip filter, so that it improves my product performance. It was working fine.

```
<property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION" value="force"/>
<property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIME_TYPES" value="text/javascript,text/css,text/html"/>
<property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIN_SIZE" value="1000"/>
```

Now, I have recently migrated to Wildfly 13, where I think, this properties are not working. So, can you please help me with this?

Also, is there any other important configuration for improving wildfly performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did research and found solution. Please search for undertow in `standalone.xml` and add filter related configuration changes as mentioned below :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:6.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <filter-ref name="gzipFilter" predicate="not min-content-size[500] and regex[pattern='(?:application/javascript|text/css|text/html|text/xml|application/json)(;.*)?', value=%{o,Content-Type}, full-match=true]"/>
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="Wildfly 13"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow"/>
        <gzip name="gzipFilter"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 2):

WildFly 13 is using Undertow as its web container instead of JbossWeb/Apache Tomcat thus those filters which are part of Tomcat are not available.
Please take a look at [Configuration GZip at Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996165/configuration-gzip-at-wildfly)