# Does Quarkus provide anything to gzip compress servlet responses?

Tags: java, servlets, gzip, quarkus, undertow

I have a Quarkus servlet application.  It's NOT a REST application.
I need to apply GZIP compression to the response.  Is there anything in Quarkus or Undertow that supports this?

I know that RestEasy does, but this is not a REST application.  It's actually a proxy around another web-service, so it makes more sense as a servlet than a REST endpoint(s).

This is the only documentation that I could find, but it only applies to REST endpoints.
https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json#gzip-support

It seems that Undertow in WildFly does support this, but I can't figure out how to apply this to Quarkus.
[Configuration GZip at Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996165/configuration-gzip-at-wildfly)

If not, can anyone recommend an open-source servlet filter that does this?
I can write my own, but I'd rather just use something that works.

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently supported, but please open an issue, it's definitely a worthwhile feature to have